# Longtable with tabularx settings

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

This is my first question here. I read many topics, but none have solved my problem.

I need to split a table (using `longtable` or other) with the `tabularx` settings. I tried `ltablex`, but this changed all the other tables in the text. I also tried `LTXtable`, but I guess I did not know how to use it properly.

Below is the code and appearance using `tabularx`, as I want it to stay using longtable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \small
    \caption{Planejamento experimental.}
    \label{tab:MatrizPlanExp}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=1\hsize}X}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15} % Espaçamento
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CCC}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Experimento nº} & \textbf{Temperatura (°C)} & \textbf{WHSV (h$^{-1}$)} \\
        \midrule
        1     & 240   & 40 \\
        2     & 240   & 45 \\
        3     & 240   & 50 \\
        4     & 240   & 55 \\
        5     & 240   & 60 \\
        6     & 260   & 40 \\
        7     & 260   & 45 \\
        8     & 260   & 50 \\
        9     & 260   & 55 \\
        10    & 260   & 60 \\
        11    & 280   & 40 \\
        12    & 280   & 45 \\
        13    & 280   & 50 \\
        14    & 280   & 50 \\
        15    & 280   & 50 \\
        16    & 280   & 55 \\
        17    & 280   & 60 \\
        18    & 300   & 5 \\
        19    & 300   & 10 \\
        20    & 300   & 20 \\
        21    & 320   & 2,5 \\
        22    & 320   & 5 \\
        23    & 320   & 10 \\
        24    & 320   & 20 \\
        25    & 340   & 2,5 \\
        26    & 340   & 5 \\
        27    & 340   & 10 \\
        28    & 340   & 20 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the best I got using `longtable` (I have increased the lines to go to the other page).

```
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}P{4cm}P{4cm}P{4cm}@{}}
    \caption{Planejamento experimental.}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Experimento nº} & \textbf{Temperatura (°C)} & \textbf{WHSV (h$^{-1}$)} \\
    \midrule
    1     & 240   & 40 \\
    2     & 240   & 45 \\
    3     & 240   & 50 \\
    4     & 240   & 55 \\
    5     & 240   & 60 \\
    6     & 260   & 40 \\
    7     & 260   & 45 \\
    8     & 260   & 50 \\
    9     & 260   & 55 \\
    10    & 260   & 60 \\
    11    & 280   & 40 \\
    12    & 280   & 45 \\
    13    & 280   & 50 \\
    14    & 280   & 50 \\
    15    & 280   & 50 \\
    16    & 280   & 55 \\
    17    & 280   & 60 \\
    18    & 300   & 5 \\
    19    & 300   & 10 \\
    20    & 300   & 20 \\
    21    & 320   & 2,5 \\
    22    & 320   & 5 \\
    23    & 320   & 10 \\
    24    & 320   & 20 \\
    25    & 340   & 2,5 \\
    26    & 340   & 5 \\
    27    & 340   & 10 \\
    28    & 340   & 20 \\
    19    & 300   & 10 \\
    20    & 300   & 20 \\
    21    & 320   & 2,5 \\
    22    & 320   & 5 \\
    23    & 320   & 10 \\
    24    & 320   & 20 \\
    25    & 340   & 2,5 \\
    26    & 340   & 5 \\
    27    & 340   & 10 \\
    28    & 340   & 20 \\
    20    & 300   & 20 \\
    21    & 320   & 2,5 \\
    22    & 320   & 5 \\
    23    & 320   & 10 \\
    24    & 320   & 20 \\
    25    & 340   & 2,5 \\
    26    & 340   & 5 \\
    27    & 340   & 10 \\
    \bottomrule
    \label{tab:MatrizPlanExp}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to:

1) Use `\small` font with `longtable` without decreasing the font of the caption.

2) Have a row closing and starting the split table.

3) Write on the dividing page that the table continues on the next page, or something like that.

Please, help me.

Comment: We'lcome to TeX SX! What do you mean with ‘ltablex changed all other tables’?

Comment: You did remove the `table` wrapper, right? You can't have a float split across pages, so you need to get rid of that.

Comment: I would never use tabularx for such a table, tabularx is designed to control line breaking within the table cells and you have no linebreaking in these kinds of data tables, so the only effect of forcing the table to be \textwidth wide is that the columns are further apart so the table is harder to read.

Comment: Bernard, with "ltablex changed all other tables" I meant that this command changed the formatting of all the other tables in my dissertation (another 20), which I configured individually.

Comment: Crf, yes, I removed "table". Still, it was not what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: David Carlisle, thanks for the response, I use \textwidth because it is required by my university, and tabularx because I can centralize the text horizontally and vertically. However, I am new user, I will continue learning here in this forum. Thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{small}
        \begin{longtable}{ p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm} }
            \caption{Planejamento experimental.} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Experimento nº}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Temperatura (°C)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{WHSV (h$^{-1}$)}} \\
            \hline
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{3}{c}
            {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Experimento nº}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Temperatura (°C)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{WHSV (h$^{-1}$)}} \\
            \hline
            \endhead
            \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
            \endfoot
            \hline
            \endlastfoot
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{1}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{240}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{40} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{2}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{240}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{45} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{3}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{240}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{50} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{4}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{240}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{55} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{5}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{240}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{60} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{6}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{260}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{40} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{7}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{260}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{45} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{8}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{260}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{50} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{9}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{260}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{55} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{10}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{260}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{60} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{11}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{280}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{40} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{12}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{280}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{45} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{13}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{280}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{50} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{14}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{280}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{50} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{15}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{280}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{50} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{16}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{280}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{55} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{17}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{280}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{60} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{18}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{300}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5 }\\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{19}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{300}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{20}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{300}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{21}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2,5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{22}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{23}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{24}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{25}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2,5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{26}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{27}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{28}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{19}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{300}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{20}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{300}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{21}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2,5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{22}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{23}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{24}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{25}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2,5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{26}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{27}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{28}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{20}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{300}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{21}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2,5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{22}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{23}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{24}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{320}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{20} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{25}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2,5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{26}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{27}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{340}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10} \\
        \end{longtable}
    \end{small}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried various means to eliminate or minimize the redundant multicolumn commands to center the fields under each column, but unfortunately, nothing seemed to work with the longtable other than the multicolumn{1} for each cell.  Trying to do a multicolumn{3} doesn't work.  I'm new at LaTeX myself and thought I'd tackle your question for my own learning.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I wanted it to go. Thank you.

Comment: Far simple is remove all `\multicolumn` and intesat them redfined table specification to `\begin{longtable}{ *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4cm}  }`.

Answer (score 6):

After three years ... this table can be write with powerful new table package `tabularray`. For better aligning numbers in  columns I would employ `siunitx` package (loaded as `tabularray` library):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
 
\begin{document}

    \begin{longtblr}[caption = {Planejamento experimental.}
                    ]%
                    {colspec={*{3}{ X[c,si]} },
                     rowhead = {1},
                     rows = {font=\small}
                    }
    \toprule
\mbox{Experimento nº}
    &  \mbox{Temperatura (\si{\celsius})}
            &  \mbox{WH{S}V (h$^{-1}$)}
                    \\
    \midrule
 1  & 240   & 40    \\
 2  & 240   & 45    \\
 3  & 240   & 50    \\
 4  & 240   & 55    \\
 5  & 240   & 60    \\
 6  & 260   & 40    \\
 7  & 45    & 45    \\
 8  & 260   & 50    \\
 9  & 260   & 55    \\
10  & 260   & 60    \\
11  & 280   & 40    \\
12  & 280   & 45    \\
13  & 280   & 50    \\
14  & 280   & 50    \\
15  & 280   & 50    \\
16  & 280   & 55    \\
17  & 280   & 60    \\
18  & 300   &  5    \\
19  & 300   & 10    \\
20  & 300   & 20    \\
21  & 320   &  2.5  \\
22  & 320   &  5    \\
23  & 320   & 10    \\
24  & 320   & 20    \\
25  & 340   &  2.5  \\
26  & 340   &  5    \\
27  & 340   & 10    \\
28  & 340   & 20    \\
19  & 300   & 10    \\
20  & 300   & 20    \\
21  & 320   &  2.5  \\
22  & 320   &  5    \\
23  & 320   & 10    \\
24  & 320   & 20    \\
25  & 340   &  2.5  \\
26  & 340   &  5    \\
27  & 340   & 10    \\
28  & 340   & 20    \\
20  & 300   & 20    \\
21  & 320   &  2.5  \\
22  & 320   &  5    \\
23  & 320   & 10    \\
24  & 320   & 20    \\
25  & 340   &  2.5  \\
26  & 340   &  5    \\
27  & 340   & 10    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Instead of

```
\mbox{Experimento nº}
    &  \mbox{Temperatura (\si{\celsius})}
            &  \mbox{WH{S}V (h$^{-1}$)}
                    \\
```

can be used

```
{{{Experimento nº}}}
    &  {{{Temperatura (\si{\celsius})}}}
            &  {{{WH{S}V (h$^{-1}$)}}}
                    \\
```

Result is the same as before, but with it the table code is more in `tabularray` spirit :-)

Comment: In version 2022B of `tabularray` to be released on June 1st, you will be able to write `row{1}={guard}` instead of three pairs of curly braces.

Comment: @L.J.R. super! This will significantly simplify writing table with `S` (`\si`) columns. BTW, I'm curious, do you know when Overleaf will upgrade its installation of the  `tabularray` package? I sow here many people, who use Overleaf` that they like to use `tabularray with functionality at least of version 2021N or newest.

Comment: Overleaf updated TeXlive 2020 and 2021 in October. So I guess they will update TeXlive 2022 in similar time.